# Taking a screenshot of web application in Javascript

Tags: javascript

This is the javascript code.

```
function fnShowSuggestion()
{
    $('#screenName').val($.trim($('h4:not(.navbar-text):first').text()));
    $('#suggest').modal();

}
```

While clicking the suggestion link, it calls this function which opens a modal popup. How to give the screenshot code to take a screenshot of the page behind the modal popup?

Comment: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#js-events
https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas
http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Comment: @SPlatten in fact it is

Comment: @FlashThunder, if you are running JS on node perhaps, but not when running JS in a browser.

Comment: @SPlatten try this example: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com , a fully JS/HTML5 solution working on client side.

Comment: @FlashThunder, learn something new everyday :)

Comment: @SPlatten I do.